# Latex Error: Using table xcolor, error is Extra \endgroup. <recently read> \endgroup \end{figure}

Tags: tables, color

When I try to use `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. Then error comes with tables figures etc
Even error comes with \begin{document} ended  by \end{figure}

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{table}.
```

I'm using these following packages in snippest
[image]

Now when I create a figure or table in document

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
1
\end{table}
....
\end{document}
```

the following error comes

[image]

Comment: There  must be something special in your document. Show a small complete example demonstrating the error.

Comment: Thanks for response, I have updated the question as per your request.

Comment: Screenshots and code snippets are not a complete example. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: I found the reason. It is because of xthesis package, but I have need of this package because my document whole format is completely depends on this package.